GitLab CICD job: Unable to commit files, The git-push command failed
I am trying to run one CICD job on GitLab, while executing this job I am getting this error.
Its clearly saying that it could not read password but from where it is reading password I am not sure? I mean where to configure this password?
I already added PROJECT_ACCESS_TOKEN for me on this project on CICD token section, still I am getting this error:
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project demo-project: Unable to commit files
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - Provider message:
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - The git-push command failed.
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - Command output:
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - fatal: could not read Password for 'https://username@gitlab.domain.net': No such device or address


Why are you using such ancient version of the maven-release-plugin (check: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/) ... Which Maven version do you use?

can you post your .gitlab-ci.yml?

Thanks for your response its more related to adding project-access-token for cicd pipline job. I found my answer and posted as answer here.

Login to git lab and select your project.
Go to setting option for project.
Click on Access Token section. 
Click on Add new token button.
Fill all information and select scope. 
Click on create project access token.
Copy name and value of this project access token and paste on notepad.
Now again go to setting option for project.
This time click on CI/CD 
Click on Varibales pane and expand it
Click on add varibale button, A form will popup
Fill description, name and value of project access token from notepad
click on add variable button.
Now project access token ready for CI/CD pipline job.
Now run your CICD job again.
It solve the issue. 

